# stop Input textbox with border overlapping containing div

Tags: html, css

My input textbox overlaps it's containing div at the end . Is there a way i can stop this from happening with out doing an exact pixel width, i want to keep it fluid for use in media queries.

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5TzQK/

thanks d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used to `box-sizing` in your **css**

```
    input.txtboxplain{
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

**[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5TzQK/1/)**

now more about box-sizing **[click here](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by adding

```
padding: 1px;
```

to your `div.sidemenubox` class.

Hope that helps!